# Weird duplicated keys in NSDictionary on iOS 5, not so on iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsdictionary

I'm using a `NSMutableDictionary` to store some values about some `UITableViewCell`s, so I'm using instances of `NSIndexPath` as keys. Everything works as expected on iOS 6, but when I run the exact same code in the iOS 5 Simulator, weird things happen. So I printed the contents of the dictionary to the console:

```
Printing description of heights:
{
    "<UIMutableIndexPath 0x6a8a3d0> 2 indexes [1, 3]" = 100;
    "<UIMutableIndexPath 0x6a8a3d0> 2 indexes [1, 3]" = 100;
    "<UIMutableIndexPath 0x6a8a3d0> 2 indexes [1, 3]" = 100;
}
```

On iOS 6 it looks like this:

```
Printing description of heights:
{
    "<UIMutableIndexPath 0x75ca8c0> 2 indexes [0, 1]" = 44;
    "<UIMutableIndexPath 0x75caa70> 2 indexes [0, 0]" = 10;
    "<UIMutableIndexPath 0x75ca500> 2 indexes [1, 0]" = 100;
    "<UIMutableIndexPath 0x717df70> 2 indexes [1, 1]" = 67;
    "<UIMutableIndexPath 0x715a3e0> 2 indexes [1, 2]" = 67;
    "<UIMutableIndexPath 0x717def0> 2 indexes [1, 3]" = 67;
}
```

Which is how it should be, obviously! Why would the dictionary on iOS 5 store different values for **exactly** the same key?

---

**Edit:** Some code...

The dictionary creating is just

```
self.heights = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

I set values using the new subscripting syntax, i.e. like so:

```
self.heights[indexPath] = minHeight;
```

(`indexPath` is a `NSIndexPath`, `minHeight` is a `NSNumber`.)

I set these values dynamically as the delegate requests them:

```
- (NSNumber *)heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (![indexPath isInTableView:self.tableView])
    {
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInvalidArgumentException reason:@"indexPath not in tableView" userInfo:nil];
    }

    NSNumber *storedHeight = self.heights[indexPath];
    if (storedHeight != nil)
    {
        return storedHeight;
    }

    NSNumber *minHeight = self.minimumHeights[indexPath];
    self.heights[indexPath] = minHeight;
    return minHeight;
}
```

The `minimumHeights` `NSDictionary` also holds `NSNumber`s for every indexPath in a table view.

Comment: You should know by now that you need to post some relevant code for anyone to be able to help at all. Show the code that populates and displays `heights`.

Comment: Best guess is there is a subtle bug in the code that is creating the `NSMutableDictionary`. Show that code. The chance that `NSMutableDictionary` or `UIMutableIndexPath` are broken in iOS5 is nil, the whole OS could not run!

Comment: The code is nothing magical, I added it now.

Comment: Yeah I guess you are right. Could it be a problem with subscripting?

Comment: If you look at the dictionary's count of objects, does it match the display?

Comment: The code of interest is the code that **sets** the values, that is where the error is.

Comment: @PhillipMills The cound of objects and count of keys both match the display.

Comment: @Zaph The only place in the class where I set a value is in the second last line of `-heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: What is `UIMutableIndexPath` and not `NSIndexPath`? Using a mutable index is a problem.

Comment: I use `NSIndexPath` in code, but apparently the framework uses `UIMutableIndexPath` by the framework. I don't use `UIMutableIndexPath` anywhere.

Comment: If you add an NSLog() to the start of heightForRowAtIndexPath, is it actually getting called 3 or 6 times in iOS5? Plausible explanation: Perhaps the hash method in iOS5's NSIndexPath is not including the section, but only the row, hence the clashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember reading about `NSIndexPath` methods `isEqual:` or `hash` or both changing in iOS6 or just that there was a bug in iOS 5. In any case, it seems you can't use them as dict keys.

Try using different keys. Maybe using its `description` method or a custom string built with the section and row.

```
#define idx2key(_ip) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d", [_ip section], [_ip row]]

...
self.heights[idx2key(indexPath)] = minHeight;
...
```

In old `NSIndexPath` Apple said:

> NSIndexPath objects are uniqued and shared. If an index path
>   containing the specified index or indexes already exists, that object
>   is returned instead of a new instance.

That paragraph doesn't exist anymore. I guess internal comparison of instances have been changed too.

Comment: The `description` method should not be used except for debugging, there is no guarantee that it will not change. Best to create something such as a NSString concatenation of the section+row.

Comment: Yep, you're right. This is why I didn't use it in the example :)

Comment: Ok, this works on both iOS 5 and 6, so thanks! But I did some small testing and found: http://pastebin.com/Pf393qxJ. Apparently, (1,0) and (0,1) both return 3 as hash, on iOS 5 **and** 6.

Comment: No problem. You will be using `NSString` hash now.